# Tangent line of a Circle with non-negative y intercepts

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Let S be the set of all points A on the circle $x^
2 + (y − 2)^2 = 1$ so that the tangent line at
A has a non-negative y-intercept; then S is the union of one or more circular arcs. Find
the total length of S

From the equation, we have the center at $(0,2)$

I let $(a,b)$ be the point that satisfies the conditions

then

$a^2 + (b-2)^2 =1$

Equation of the tangent line on the line from $(0,2)$ and $(a,b)$

= $\frac{a}{2-b}(x-a) = y-b$

= $\frac{ax}{2-b} + \frac{a^2}{b-2}+b = y$

y Intercept must be non-negative

therefore,

$\frac{a^2+b^2-2b}{b-2} > 0$

Using the Circle Equation.

=$\frac{2b-3}{b-2} > 0$

therefore, [3/2, 2] are the bounds, which has 15 degrees, but the answer is not 23/12 pi. I don't know where I went wrong, and I think what I did was reasonable, I am also asking for solutions that are shorter than this one. Thanks!

Comment: You have to exclude two arcs of $15^{\circ}.$ Note that you only got $b.$ So if $(a,b)$ is one point where the condition is not satisfied then $(-a,b)$ is also a point.

Comment: ooh, Im still missing 30 deg of arc though as the answer is 5pi/3

Comment: I didn't check the measure of your arcs. Why do you it is $15$ degrees? I get that any of them measures $30$ degrees.

Comment: Oh wait im stupid, it is 30 deg